# Flutter app on iOS cannot start after change in camera permission

Tags: ios, flutter, permissions, crash

I have following problem. Everything is working fine on emulator, but physical device has following issue. My app is using camera. When user allow camera everything is OK, but problem is when he decline it after some time for whatever reason. After declining app crash on startup, it crash also when he enable it again. Basically after changing camera permission app cannot start and crash. Any idea how to fix it ? Thanks

Note: I tried to kill app manually, but it still not start. Only starting app again from xcode is working

Comment: Can you share the stack trace? Also the code you have for handling the permission?